# Opacity FadeIn and FadeOut Problems - FadeOut Failing CSS Only

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I cannot figure out why my fadeout is not working for an overlay I am putting together.
I would like to achieve most of this with css.  The only time I want to use jQuery is when I toggle a display: block class after a delay.

What do I need to do so that the fadeout of the overlay works nicely after a brief delay?

I am also including a CodePen.  https://codepen.io/ChidoYo/pen/jOmdZLK

HTML

```
    <div class="container border rounded mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col pb-3">
          <h1>Opacity Fade In/Out</h1>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="toggle">Toggle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="superposer d-none"></div>
    <div class="drawer">
      <div class="row mx-0 mt-4">
        <div class="col">
          <h3>Drawer</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.superposer {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
      opacity: 0;
      // transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 2s;
      animation: superposerFadeOut 1s ease-in-out 2s;

      &.active {
        opacity: 1;
        // transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        animation: superposerFadeIn 0.5s ease-in-out;
      }
    }

    @keyframes superposerFadeOut {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    @keyframes superposerFadeIn {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    .drawer {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out;
      right: -350px;
      background-color: white;
      border-left: 1px solid #999;
      width: 350px;

      &.active {
        transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
        right: 0;
      }
    }
```

jQuery

```
$(() => {
      $('#toggle').on('click', () => {
        $('.superposer').toggleClass('active d-none');
        $('.drawer').addClass('active');
      });

      $('.superposer').on('click', () => {
        $('.superposer').removeClass('active');
        $('.drawer').removeClass('active');

        setTimeout(() => {
          $('.superposer').addClass('d-none')
        }, 1000)
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few small issues with your code. The main reason as to why your `.superposer` does not fade out is because you are using `display: none` when it is not active. `display` cannot be animated/transitioned, since both these properties require a range of values that can be calculated. `display` has boolean values. It is either on, or off. There's nothing in between.

So just deleting the `display` lines in `.superposer` will make the FadeOut animation start working. However it won't be the behaviour you expect, because you need to make some changes to your JS as well.

I've made a codepen with these changes. You can have look at it here: https://codepen.io/OSquiddy/pen/ExmrMzX

I've also gotten rid of the animations, since what you want can easily be done with a transition instead.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've been trying to avoid using JS completely.  Unfortunately I need the superposer (which is another name for overlay) to change to display: none when hidden  because of screen readers.   My approach will have to be to use a very small amount of JS to toggle the display block/none with the use of a timeout.

Comment: For that I'd suggest using a transitionend eventListener instead of a timer. It's best not to rely on timers. You can listen for when the transition ends on superposer, check to see if it's opacity value is 0, and then change display to none

Comment: Fantastic suggestion!  I will look into it.

Comment: Here is my codepen with the solution: https://codepen.io/ChidoYo/pen/jOmdZLK